# Login Loop in Ubuntu 16.04 after editing the Path

Tags: command-line, bash, login, paths, pam-environment

I was editing the path as said in this page: [Source](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/modify-path-ubuntu-52030.html)

After I did that, I logged out, and ever since that, I was not able to Login.

I have tried various Login Loop Remedies said in this Exchange, but was not possible.

I think the error was due to the fact that, I may have entered a wrong path first and then appended the remaining path as said in the Source page:

```
PATH=/path/to/command/directory:$PATH
```

Is there a solution to revert back and able to login normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried logging in at a text terminal:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- Enter user name then password

If you can log in this way you could temporarily rename *~/.pam_environment*:

```
mv ~/.pam_environment ~/.pam_environment.bak
```

Then switch back to the graphical login (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) and try again.